# Tips on using webview to play an embedded Flash movie

Tags: basic4android

I've tried (without success) to get a video to play within a webview. I can see the video thumbnail with the default play button overlaying the video.

When I click the play button - the entire video hi-lights in transparent yellowish/orange. Clicking play again causes the Play button to blink. The thumbnail always remains, but never plays. I can even see the timeline below the video with the play-head, etc. I can never touch the video controls, because every click treats the entire video like one big button - and hi-lights like mentioned above.

They are numerous videos to be played and they are not at YouTube, so launching the YT player with an intent isn't desired.

I'm using SDK 8 (2.2), runing on a 2.3.6 device, and Have the latest Flash Player 11.xxxxx installed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Took another approach in the app.

Comment: What was that other approach?